# int.Parse(textBox1.Text) error

Tags: c#, winforms, parsing, textbox, int

I am getting error `int pocet = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);`

It says that data have some bad format, but I am writing only natural numbers to TextBox1

Comment: Show us an example of the string in your textbox, and the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: What is the text in textBox1.Text?

Comment: Obviously, you don't. What exactly do you write into the TextBox?

Comment: Try `int pocet = int.Parse(textBox1.Text.Trim());` // guessing spaces (invisible but exist) for user it looks like correct input.

Comment: Could be the text box is empty? -> String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) is true?

Comment: This is an XY problem.  Y is the bomb you get from trying to parse an empty string.  X is probably getting the form reference wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've either got an empty string there, there's whitespace at the start or end, or you're writing in the thousands separators.

You can instruct the Int32.Parse method to handle some of those cases like this:

```
Int32.Parse(
   "  -12,340  ",
   NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite |
   NumberStyles.AllowThousands |
   NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite |
   NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign,
   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```

Note the current culture bit at the end is important because the thousands separator will be different depending on the culture the user has their computer set to.

This still won't handle an empty string though - just check to see if the string is empty before doing the parsing.

Comment: @Dunemaster, this is quite close to what I've encountered...   I have gone to the point of pre-forcing a leading zero so there is never an empty string... such as Int32.Parse( "0" + yourTextbox.Text);

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use the TryParse method that will no throw an exception when there is bad data, but will allow you to use control flow and logic to handle it:

```
  int number;
  bool result = Int32.TryParse(TextBox.Text.Trim(), out number);
  if (result)
  {
     //Carry On/    
  }
  else
  {
     //Handle input error
  }
```

Comment: `TryParse` just catches the exception for you.  It doesn't answer the original question of why the input is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

if you using natural number then use

NumericUpDown Control

```
int pocet = int.Parse(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Probably the better long-term solution, even though it doesn't address the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int intValueFromTbx = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)
```

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(string) actually calls Int32.Parse, so this will leave the OP with exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

> Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

Also debug to make sure you have only integer numbers in the `textBox1.Text` at conversion time.

Comment: Hi Leo - Convert.ToInt32(string) actually calls Int32.Parse, so this will leave the OP with exactly the same error.

Comment: so i think the solution is DEBUG!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method :

```
int pocet = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString());
```

Comment: The Text property is already of type string... so calling ToString() won't help here :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.... make sure you use the right Cap number 
9　and 
 ９
the first one will work, and the second won't!

Hope this helps

@txshon